# why not working click event from variable

Tags: imacros

I have simple macros, that must go to website and then do 30 times click on element.
Here is my macros, what i'm doing wrong?

```
var macros, follow,start;
macros = "CODE:";
macros += "URL GOTO=http://twiends.com/home" + "\n";
follow += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:'netfollow twitter'" + "\n";
iimPlay(macros)
for (i=1 ;i < 30; i++) {
    start = iimPlay(follow); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like so:

```
var macros, follow, start;
macros = "CODE:";
macros += "URL GOTO=http://twiends.com/home" + "\n";
iimPlay(macros);
follow = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:'netfollow twitter'" + "\n";
for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    start = iimPlayCode(follow); 
}
```